# changing posts layout in ultimate member profile plugin

Tags: plugins, customization, templates

I would like for it to be a grid than stacked posts as a lot of empty space looks bad. I am new to customizations and not sure how to make this particular change.

I tried making some changes from CSS but that has not helped.

Here's the template that renders this particular view:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
    //Only for AJAX loading posts
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            UM()->shortcodes()->set_args = array( 'post' => $post );
            UM()->shortcodes()->load_template( 'profile/posts-single' );
        }
    }
} else {
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) { ?>
        <div class="um-ajax-items">

            <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                UM()->shortcodes()->set_args = array( 'post' => $post );
                UM()->shortcodes()->load_template( 'profile/posts-single' );
            }

            if ( $count_posts > 10 ) { ?>
                <div class="um-load-items">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="um-ajax-paginate um-button" data-hook="um_load_posts"
                       data-author="<?php echo esc_attr( um_get_requested_user() ); ?>" data-page="1"
                       data-pages="<?php echo esc_attr( ceil( $count_posts / 10 ) ); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'load more posts', 'ultimate-member' ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="um-profile-note">
            <span>
                <?php if ( um_profile_id() == get_current_user_id() ) {
                    _e( 'You have not created any posts.', 'ultimate-member' );
                } else {
                    _e( 'This user has not created any posts.', 'ultimate-member' );
                } ?>
            </span>
        </div>

    <?php }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some basic CSS which would help make things a grid on Desktop and stacked on Mobile:

```
.um-profile-body.posts.posts-default {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .um-profile-body.posts.posts-default {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.um-ajax-items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .um-ajax-items {
    grid-template-columns: 33.3fr 33.3fr 33.3fr;
    grid-gap: 0px;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much :)